# Ports not being exposed even after adding Firewall Rules in Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, port

I have added firewall rules for my Google Cloud VM instance to expose a port (i.e. 3306). But, the port is not being exposed even after the rules are added. I am allowing connection from any IP.

What is possibly going wrong? I have followed a few tutorials and followed proper steps.

Comment: what is your firewall rule? and how you are testing that port is not exposed?

Comment: You can test with tcpdump if you are receiving traffic on vm or not. Install tcpdump on your vm and listen on port 3306.

Comment: I have pinged the port and also checked from a third-party website.

Comment: It might possible that traffic is reaching to vm but no service is responding on 3306 port. You can verify this with tcpdump.

Comment: The flow come from where ? what is the rule that you defined? can you provide detail on your env ?

Comment: Port 3306 means MySQL. How did you configure the listening port on MySQL? If it is only listening on a Unix socket or localhost, then it is not available outside the instance. Edit your question with the results for `netstat -tulpn | grep 3306`. Add your MySQL configuration files. The MySQL configuration files are usually in `/etc/mysql` but this is OS dependent.